# How to pass parameter in a class for Argparse by factoring two very similar classes

Tags: python, oop, argparse

I have the following codes:

```
def main(args):
    """
    Description of main
    """
    print args


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class DefaultListAction(argparse.Action):
        CHOICES = ['ann','netmhcpan','comblib_sidney2008','consensus','smm','smmpmbec','netmhccons']
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            if values:
                for value in values:
                    if value not in self.CHOICES:
                        message = ("invalid choice: {0!r} (choose from {1})"
                                .format(value,
                                        ', '.join([repr(action)
                                                    for action in self.CHOICES])))

                        raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, message)
                setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

    class DefaultListAction_Frames(argparse.Action):
        CHOICES = ['R','F','6']
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            if values:
                for value in values:
                    if value not in self.CHOICES:
                        message = ("invalid choice: {0!r} (choose from {1})"
                                .format(value,
                                        ', '.join([repr(action)
                                                    for action in self.CHOICES])))

                        raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, message)
                setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("-iedb",help="IEDB tools options: ann, comblib_sydney2008, consensus, netmhcpan, smm, smmpmbec, netmhccons", \
              action=DefaultListAction, nargs='*', default=[''], \
              metavar='iedb_tools')
    parser.add_argument("-f",help="Frame to translate insert: (F)orward three frames, (R)everse three frames or (6) frames F + B.  Default F.", \
              action=DefaultListAction_Frames, nargs=1, default=['F'], \
              metavar='frames')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Basically, there are two `argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument()` , each of them t takes one of the classes as parameter in `action`.

My question is how can   factorize `class DefaultListAction(argparse.Action)`  and class `DefaultListAction_Frames(argparse.Action)`, given that the only differences between the two is `CHOICES` parameter.

And how can I pass those `CHOICES`  as parameter in `argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument()`

Comment: `self.choices` should contain the `choices` parameter given in the `add_argument`.  See the `__init__` for the `Action` class.  `action.choices` is used in the `_check_value` method, and in help formatting.  It's not used in any `Action` method, but I don't know any reason why it can't.

Comment: @hpaulj: example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add_argument` `choices` parameter is available as `self.choices`.  It isn't used in any of existing `Action` subclasses, but there's no reason it shouldn't.

It will used by the parser to test the values before they get passed to the `Action.__call__`.  In this test that doesn't appear to conflict with your own use, but I can't rule that out.

`action.choices` are also used in help formatting, though the `metavar` parameter overrides that.

```
class ListAction(argparse.Action):
    # change self.CHOICES to self.choices
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if values:
            for value in values:
                if value not in self.choices:
                    message = ("invalid choice: {0!r} (choose from {1})"
                            .format(value,
                                    ', '.join([repr(action)
                                                for action in self.choices])))

                    raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, message)
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

# should behave just like the -f argument
parser.add_argument("-g",help="Frame to translate insert: (F)orward three frames, (R)everse three frames or (6) frames F + B.  Default F.", \
          action=ListAction, nargs=1, default=['F'], \
          choices=['R','F','6'])
```

help allowing `choices` as the metavar (for illustration purposes)

```
2304:~/mypy$ python stack41562756.py -h
usage: stack41562756.py [-h] [-iedb [iedb_tools [iedb_tools ...]]] [-f frames]
                        [-g {R,F,6}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -iedb [iedb_tools [iedb_tools ...]]
                        IEDB tools options: ann, comblib_sydney2008, consensus, netmhcpan, smm, smmpmbec, netmhccons
  -f frames             Frame to translate insert: (F)orward three frames, (R)everse three frames or (6) frames F + B.  Default F.
  -g {R,F,6}            Frame to translate insert: (F)orward three frames, (R)everse three frames or (6) frames F + B.  Default F.
```

When parsing `action.choices` is only used in `_check_value`, which is called by `_get_values`.

```
def _check_value(self, action, value):
    # converted value must be one of the choices (if specified)
    if action.choices is not None and value not in action.choices:
        args = {'value': value,
                'choices': ', '.join(map(repr, action.choices))}
        msg = _('invalid choice: %(value)r (choose from %(choices)s)')
        raise ArgumentError(action, msg % args)
```

Off hand it looks like you could use the default `store` action with `choices`:

```
parser.add_argument("-e",help="Frame to translate insert: (F)orward three frames, (R)everse three frames or (6) frames F + B.  Default F.", \
          nargs=1, default=['F'], choices=['R','F','6'])
```

I don't see anything in your custom actions that's different.  But I haven't studied or tested them in detail.

=================

Another approach is to just subclass one of your new Actions:

```
class DefaultListAction_Frames(DefaultListAction):
    CHOICES = ['R','F','6','X']
```

If the `__call__` method is the same, you don't have to repeat it.

Another approach is to use a factory function to give each `DefaultListAction` Action its own `CHOICES` attribute.  The `FileType` is such a class - it creates a custom `type` function.

The `type` function is another place where you could customize the value checking.  `type` is intended for value conversion and testing, while custom Action classes are most useful if you want to save values in some special way.